# Link Javascript in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using php web framework codeignter, I would want to access my link on Javascript, I've tried

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo "assets/main.js;?>"></script>`.

Autoload url helper is enabled but it doesn't load my Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/main.js");?>" </script>

Comment: @kumar i've loaded my css using the code above, will this work with Javascript?

Comment: yes. Give the correct path to js file.

Comment: @chris if Your above code work with php then it will 100% work with javascript. first thing you make sure that "assets" is properly defined or not.

Comment: @ripa I'm on WAMP server Javascript is supposed to work on a local environment right?

Comment: @chris it's not dependent on xampp or wamp. "assets" is codeigniter feature. If you are not familiar with "assets" then my suggession is to avoid "assets". use full path to define folder path.

Comment: try this `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/main.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple and clean way is here:

create a helper class:

create a `utility_helper.php` class in helper folder and only put the below code in the `utility_helper.php`

code to put: (with `<?php ...below code here... ?>`)

```
function asset_url(){
  return base_url().'assets/';
}
```

open your `autoload.php` and make sure you include `utility` in `autoload['helper']` array:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','utility','file','form','etc...');
```

important:
now create `assets` folder at the same location where you have your `system and application`
folders.. and put your all `css` and `js` files and folder in `assets folder`

now you can link your css and js in `view` like below:

```
<script src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>css/style.css"/>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

GOOD LUCK :)